# Send mail using Powershell behind a proxy

Tags: email, proxy, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to send an e-mail by using Powershell and GMail, and for now, I managed to do so with this function:

```
function sendMail{
    $EmailFrom = “me@gmail.com”
    $EmailTo = “info@company.com”
    $Subject = “Subject”
    $Body = “Hellow”
    $SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“username”, “password”);
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

    Write-Host "All done!"
}
```

And this script works just fine if it wasn't the fact we are using a Proxy within our network. How can I modify this function in order to be able to send e-mails in combination with the Proxy.
In other words, how can I connect to the Proxy and send an e-mail by using an external SMTP server.

Comment: dude, did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP and HTTPS proxies don't allow SMTP connections to pass through them.

If you are using a SOCKS proxy, then you can tunnel all your TCP connections through it including SMTP connections which uses TCP.

You can then use [WideCap](http://widecap.ru/en/) to socksify all the applications or you can use [Component pro .Net SMTP client](http://www.componentpro.com/doc/mail/Connecting-through-a-proxy-server3.htm) which supports proxy

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen software. TY